# Excel for Mac (15.33) not remembering recently used files

Tags: macos, ms-office

For some reason, Excel for Mac (15.33) is not remembering recently used files.  How do I fix this?

I'm not using Office 365.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I decided to pin a document in the `File Open` dialog:

[image]

after doing so, the `Open Recent` menu was populated.

** edit **

After closing and restarting Excel, the problem reoccurred.

Answer (score 1):

Great news. Fixed in Office 2019 version 16.29.1 (19091700 for Mac.

Answer (score -1):

The problem was fixed years ago, but has returned to all Word, Excel and PowerPoint 2019 version 16.29.0 (19090802) for Mac released yesterday: they only show "File - Open Recent - More" and not any recent item there! Somebody knows how to fix it or is this an Office bug?